# multiprocessinq.Queue as attribute of Queue.Queue child

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out what the following module is doing.

```
import Queue
import multiprocessing
import threading

class BufferedReadQueue(Queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self, lim=None):
        self.raw = multiprocessing.Queue(lim)
        self.__listener = threading.Thread(target=self.listen)
        self.__listener.setDaemon(True)
        self.__listener.start()
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, lim)

    def listen(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.put(self.raw.get())
        except:
            pass

    @property
    def buffered(self):
        return self.qsize()
```

It is only instantiated once in the calling code, and the `.raw` attribute, multiprocessing.Queue, gets sent to another class, which appears to inherit from `multiprocessing.Process`.

So as I'm seeing it, an attribute of BufferedReadQueue is being used as a Queue, but not the class (nor an instance of it) itself.

What would be a reason that BufferedReadQueue inherits from Queue.Queue and not just `object`, if it's not actually being used as a queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `BufferedReadQueue` is meant to be used as a way to convert the read end of a `multiprocessing.Queue` into a normal `Queue.Queue`. Note this in `__init__`:

```
    self.__listener = threading.Thread(target=self.listen)
    self.__listener.setDaemon(True)
    self.__listener.start()
```

This starts up a listener thread, which just constantly tries to `get` items from the internal `multiprocessing.Queue`, and then `put`s all those items to `self`. It looks like the use-case is something like this:

```
def func(queue):
   queue.put('stuff')
   ...

buf_queue = BufferedReadQueue()
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(buf_queue.raw,))
proc.start()
out = buf_queue.get()  # Only get calls in the parent
```

Now, why would you do this instead of just using the `multiprocessing.Queue` directly? Probably because `multiprocessing.Queue` has some shortcomings that `Queue.Queue` doesn't. For example `qsize()`, which this `BufferedReadQueue` uses, [is not reliable with `multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize):

> Return the approximate size of the queue. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable.
>
> Note that this may raise `NotImplementedError` on Unix platforms like Mac OS X where `sem_getvalue()` is not implemented.

It's also possible to introspect a `Queue.Queue`, and peek at its contents without popping them. This isn't possible with a `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: Am seeing that the `.buffered` is called at one point. I'm *still* confused about the property decorator. In this case, is `.buffered` similar to saying `self.buffered=self.qsize()`, but making it a read only attribute?

Comment: @MikeiLL For whatever reason the author decided they wanted to use `buf_queue.buffered` instead of `buf_queue.qsize()`. Perhaps because the object is meant to be an abstraction for a buffer of objects, rather than a queue of objects, and `buffered` should be understood as "how many objects are buffered". Or maybe they want to be able to change in internal implementation of the `BufferedReadQueue` in the future, possibly in a way that means the value of `buffered` is no longer `qsize()`.

Comment: What is happening at `Queue.Queue.__init__(self, lim)`? Does that essentially assign an instance of `Queue.Queue(lim)` to the instance of `BufferedReadQueue`?

Comment: @MikeiLL It's just calling the parent class' constructor. `BufferedReaderQueue` is a child of `Queue.Queue`, so it needs to call `Queue.Queue`'s `__init__` from its own `__init__`, so that it gets properly initialized. It's just standard object-oriented programming. You might be more used to seeing `super(BufferedReaderQueue, self).__init__(limt)`, but I think `Queue.Queue` is an old-style class in Python 2.x, so you can't use `super`.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say that I'm used to seeing any of this, but I vaguely remember reading that in "Python In a Nutshell". I did read earlier today (in the same book) that Queue.Queue is and old-style class.